# Indexing 2D Numpy Array Using Function

Tags: python, numpy

I am working with a large 2D array, let's call it X. I would like to modify only the entries of X that satisfy a certain condition, so for example

```
X_{ij} = something, if f(X_{ij}) < 0
X_{ij} = no change, if f(X_{ij}) > 0
```

Is there an easy way of doing this as a one liner as opposed to looping through all value?

Comment: `x[f(x) < 0] = something[f(x) < 0]`

Comment: @MateenUlhaq So simple, thank you!